# Get application installdir by product code in c++

Tags: windows-installer

I have c++ console application and i want to get the msi installed application INSTALLDIR(the value where is software actually installed). I have applications product code. 
 
What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this code works just fine:

```
wchar_t installDirPrev[4096];
DWORD isBuffer = 4096;
MsiGetProductInfo(productCode, INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION, installDirPrev, &isBuffer);
```

Comment: I've seen scenarios (after patching and/or upgrading) will INSTALLLOCATION no longer has the correct value.

Comment: Thank your for reply! So what is the reliable way to get the directory where is msi installed?

Comment: It is my installshield made msi.

Comment: If the scope is one MSI, I'd record the installation in a registry value and just use that.  There are other techniques such as resolving components but that can cause source resolution to occur.  This way your application doesn't have to know anything about MSI API calls.

Comment: Yes, write the installation location INSTALLDIR to the registry during fresh installation so it is always available to read back.

Answer (score 1):

MsiGetProductInfo for the location only if your setup has a type 51 custom action that sets ARPINSTALLLOCATION to the actual installation folder. Not all of them do.